# Tikz, rectangle split, first part aligned abnormally

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

Some little code two draw a rectangle with 4 parts, from library `shapes.multiparts`.

```
\tikzset{
    font=\sffamily,
    BLOCK/.style={
        draw,
        align=center,
        text height=0.4cm,
        draw=red!50,
        fill=red!20,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1, 
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (h1) {host\_entry};
    \node[BLOCK=4, below=0 of h1]{
        \nodepart{one}dpid \nodepart{two}port
        \nodepart{three}IP\nodepart{four}MAC};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Every thing is OK except for the **first column** of the rectangle, the text just aligns weirdly.

[image: weird first column]

Has anyone else encountered the same issue? And how to solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to [TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). By adding a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), other users can help you with your problem in a faster rate!

Comment: Without actually testing it, I'm thinking adding a `\strut` to each of those text entries would help.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, you are indeed right. However adding to all of them will cause similar displacement but with a minor magnitude. Instead adding it to only the first element solves the problem. I would suggest to test and post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in the manual, the `rectangle split part align` key could help here. By default it is set to `center` so all the boxes that contain the node part contents are aligned by their centers, but I expect `base` is what is required.

However, what does seem to be a bug, is that the alignment doesn't affect the first part.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    font=\sffamily,
    BLOCK/.style={
        draw,
        align=center,
        text height=0.4cm,
        draw=red!50,
        fill=red!20,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1, 
    }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \align [count=\y] in {top, center, base, bottom}{
    \node at (0,-\y*2) (h1) {host\_entry};
    \node[BLOCK=4, below=0 of h1,
    label=left:\align,
    rectangle split part align=\align]{
        \nodepart{one}dpid \nodepart{two}port
        \nodepart{three}IP\nodepart{four}MAC};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In my comment, I suggested a `\strut` on each data entry, which is a zero-width rule that extends over the full vertical width of all the font's glyphs (as high as the highest capital letter, and as low as the lowest descending letter).  In this way, all entries will have uniform height, and any vertical-centering algorithm will thus find all the baselines at uniform height.

BUT!!!  That fixed the second entry, but not the first, in the OP's MWE:

[image]

Upon further exploration, I found that `\smash`ing the first data entry HAD NO EFFECT, whatsoever.  Thus, the first `\nodepart` appears pre-smashed to `tikz`, whereas the latter `\nodepart`s do not.  I don't know tikz, but if I didn't know better, this smells like a bug.

To fix the issue, I had to manually apply a `\raisebox` to the first `\nodepart`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    font=\sffamily,
    BLOCK/.style={
        draw,
        align=center,
        text height=0.4cm,
        draw=red!50,
        fill=red!20,
        rectangle split, 
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1, 
    }
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (h1) {host\_entry};
    \node[BLOCK=4, below=0 of h1]{
        \nodepart{one}\raisebox{1.3pt}{dpid}\strut\nodepart{two}port\strut
        \nodepart{three}IP\strut\nodepart{four}MAC\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]